# Interpreting mysql errors in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a use case where I have to execute a set of alter table queries on my DB and all the queries are to do with adding foreign key constraints.

Let's say there are 2 tables `A` and `B`, `A.id` references `B.id`, but some `A.id` are not present in `B.id` which I can just delete as I'm not interested in such records.

But I can't just delete them since there are few tables that are referencing table `A`'s columns.

This dependency grows like a tree. Now I want to resolve this dependency programmatically.

Is there any existing library I can use for this (preferably php)?

I should be able to interpret the SQL errors and construct the appropriate query based on the errors and execute them.

We can safely assume that all these errors are foreign key constraints which are conflicting.

Comment: Those are UPDATE queries.

Comment: Not update queries. They are alter table queries for adding foreign keys. In my use case, it fails only when I want to add foreign key from A to B and since A has id which are not present in B, I should remove such records from A. But there may a table C that has foreign key referencing a different column of A. This dependency tree can get very big. So there should be some way of extracting the error info from mysql exceptions and construct the right sql query

Comment: Doesn't this then point to a fundamental flaw in your design?!?!

Comment: Yes it is a flaw. The problem is we were using a DB schema config file to define the DB schema. But while executing sql queries according to this schema, some of the foreign key constraints have been missed out. Hence I'm looking for a way to resolve now before it is too late when I end up with too many junk data in DB

Comment: I accept that I know nothing about your schema, but it seems odd that the problem is so big that it needs to be solved programmatically. Normally, there might be only a dozen or so tables, with perhaps 3 or 4 FK contraints associated with each. Tedious though it may be, in that scenario I'd prefer to fix it by hand.